# AWS PHP SDK for Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm new to AWS,
Needed an AWS PHP SDK code to fetch Number of Instances attached to an ELB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Web Services (AWS) really shines when it comes to documentation. You can find a lot of useful information on the [AWS SDK for PHP landing page](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/); specifically you'll want to check out the [API reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/).

In the API reference, you'll see documentation on all the usual suspects: EC2, S3, and even [ELB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.ElasticLoadBalancing.ElasticLoadBalancingClient.html).

A bunch of methods are supported by the ELB client. But the one you're interested in is [DescribeLoadBalancers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-elasticloadbalancing-2012-06-01.html#describeloadbalancers). You pass in the name of your load balancer, and it spits back a description of it -- or multiple, if you pass multiple load balancer names. The description format is shown in the documentation:

```
 [
    'LoadBalancerDescriptions' => [
        [
            // ...
            'Instances' => [
                [
                   'InstanceId' => '<string>',
                ],
                // ...
            ],
            // ...
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    'NextMarker' => '<string>',
]
```

What you're looking for is the array of *Instances* in the load balancer description. This is an array of structs of type [Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-elasticloadbalancing-2012-06-01.html#shape-instance). Finally, using that array of structs, you can get the *InstanceId*'s you're looking for.

Comment: could you help me out?

Comment: $client = ElasticLoadBalancingClient::factory(array(
                'credentials' => array(
                    'key'    => 'something',
    
                    'secret' => 'something',
                ),
                'region'  => 'us-east-1',
            ));
            
            $client->describeLoadBalancers();

Comment: Please update your question to clarify: what the issue is, what additional steps you've taken, and how the community can reproduce. It would be a great help! If you're having trouble, refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my confusing quesion, although I was able to figure out with your help. :) Following made it work -

$credentials = new Credentials('accesskey', 'secretkey');

```
        $client = ElasticLoadBalancingClient::factory(array(
                    'credentials' => $credentials,
                    'region' => 'us-west-2'
        ));

        $model = $client->describeLoadBalancers();

        $ELBdata = array();

        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($model); $i++)
        {
            $output = array();

            $output['ELBName'] = $model['LoadBalancerDescriptions'][$i]['LoadBalancerName'];

            $output['DNSName'] = $model['LoadBalancerDescriptions'][$i]['DNSName'];

            $output['instanceCount'] = count($model['LoadBalancerDescriptions'][$i]['Instances']);

            array_push($ELBdata,$output);
        }

        $ELB["status"] = true;
        $ELB["data"] = $ELBdata;

        echo json_encode($ELB);
```